# Can autofill in Chrome be reduced to single fields

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete

I find the autofill features in webbrowsers very useful.  But I prefer to fill in each field of a form seperately, which can be extremely fast by using only Tab and arrow-down keys.

Unfortunately Chrome always wants to autocomplete the whole form at once.  This often leads to a situation where information is autofilled, that is not necessary to submit the form or even may be not correct (eg. company email vs. private email as I am using the same browser for various tasks)

Is it possible to keep some kind of autocomplete functionality per field, while avoiding filing fields outside the scope of the cursor?  Disabling autofill seems to disable any form field filling.

Comment: There is a [feature request/bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=83347) for this exact problem.  
The bad news is, it's status is `WontFix` :(

Comment: @MarcusMangelsdorf makes me wonder if the developers use the features they develop... That's an obvious feature request for anyone who used a bit the autofill feature.

Answer (score 5):

It's very hackish way but I found a trick to achieve the same.

So you should go to `chrome://settings/addresses?search=address`

Now create multiple addresses, each with only one field filled. So one should only have your E-Mail, another record should contain only your first name only, and so on.

Comment: I tried this and it worked fine initially. The problem is that the next time you fill a form, Google will save that address in full and then you will be back to where you were before. It seems there is no way to tell Google to only autofill address details and not to save future addresses. The option is called "save and fill addresses" which can be toggled on and off, no option to toggle "save" and "fill" individually. See related question: https://superuser.com/questions/1386595/chrome-stop-saving-adresses-and-keep-filling-those-saved-before

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of customizing Chrome's auto-fill on a per-field basis.

One alternative is to use the [Lastpass Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lastpass/hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd?hl=en), where you can decide which field to be remembered on a per-site basis.