# Chrome stop saving addresses and keep filling those saved before

Tags: google-chrome, auto-form-fill, address

I am a web developer, I create loads and loads of different forms with autocomplete option. During the process, I save a lot of dummy addresses, emails and phone numbers, and all of those are saved in my chrome browser with this option selected:

[image: Setting]

What I need is to make my Chrome store (and autofill) my data added by hand only, and not to remember everything I give it during the development process.

Scenarios I consider helpful and don't know how to achieve:

- Add addresses by hand and stop Chrome from adding new addresses in-flight
- Tell Chrome not to save addresses for particular domains
- An extension with a simple, editable shortcut to switch the option visible on the screenshot

I did my research and found nothing.

The scenario I will not consider is creating a separated account for web development.

Comment: Can't you just toggle that button when needed?

Comment: for  me, it asks "save information?"

Answer (score 1):

This is still not fully possible in Chrome by default. If you turn it off, the data is kept, but autofill choices don't appear. And if it's on, it nags you to save new data, which can be easily misclicked.

However, there are bunch of helpful extensions. For example [Autofill](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autofill/nlmmgnhgdeffjkdckmikfpnddkbbfkkk). It has these helpful features:

- it stores only data you specifically tell it to store
- it has profiles, so you can save some testing data in one profile and your regular data in another main profile
- profiles can also be applied to only specific website(s)
- it autofills by default, but you can also switch to manual mode in settings if you'd like it to work similarly to Chrome's feature